# « Manière de s’y prendre », « moyen » ou « technique »

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

-Je dois te dire une chose. Aujourd’hui je suis allé voir un psychiatre avec l’usager dont j’ai la charge, et le praticien lui a lancé des injures à deux reprises: tu es crétin, toi, hein?! Un vrai crétin.

-C’est peut-être une manière de s’y prendre/moyen/technique qui s’inscrit dans une quelconque thérapie comportementale voire une thérapie encore au stade expérimental. [ironie]

Comment: l''usager dont j'ai la charge?  Quésaco?

Comment: https://www.academie-francaise.fr/en-charge-de-en-responsabilite-de-en-capacite-de

Comment: https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_c&page=9Qs7SqSH9wdw.html

Comment: Des personnes non autonomes: autistes, déficients intellectuels, personnes aux prises avec des troubles du comportement les rendant non fonctionnelles en société, etc.

Comment: https://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=1198745

Comment: @Sé1lanceLaléa merci!

Comment: Avoir la charge d'une personne non autonome, etc, je veux bien. *avoir la charge d'un usager* [d'un service publique], ça fait bizarre. Et ce n'est pas la peine de me citer les dicos. Je comprends les termes en soi.

Comment: @Lambie Je comprends, je pensais que ton commentaire faisait référence à la formule « avoir la charge de », vu que j’avais apporté des modifications dans les détails à ce sujet.

Comment: Il y a des façons de s'y prendre. :)

Comment: @Sé1lanceLaléa On revient à la moralisation, je vois,  au lieu de s'en tenir au thème linguistique et sémantique. La seule personne qui parle de  censure c'est toi, pas moi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1/ **manière de s'y prendre**      Cette locution a la marque d'un registre assez familier et elle est plus proprement applicable dans les contextes où sont concernés non pas l'expertise professionnelle mais plutôt l'expérience de la vie de la personne dont on dit qu'elle a une manière de s'y prendre d'une sorte ou d'une autre ou dont on discute de la manière de s'y prendre dans une circonstance quelconque. Le domaine d'application selon cette prédilection est néanmoins vaste et peut concerner tout aussi bien  la manière de mettre des chaussures sans un chausse-pied que la manière de demander quelqu'un en marriage, en passant par celle de se débarrasser d'un démarcheur au porte à porte qui insiste trop ou d'obtenir un gigot juteux lorsqu'on le cuit au four. Ce n'est donc pas une expression très appropriée dans ce context qu'on peut, sans risque de se tromper, catégoriser comme professionnel.

2/ **moyen**      Ce mot est plus approprié ; il n'est pas familier, mais il est très général et pas utilisé particulièrement pour des opérations qui relèvent d'un domaine technique ou artistique, bien qu'il puisse l'être (par exemple lorsque le terme technique vient d'être utilisé).

- La sérigraphie est la technique qui permet l'impression de motifs au moyen d'écrans. C'est un moyen d'impression qui peut être utilisé sur de nombreux matériaux.

Le problème est donc la trop grande généralité.

3/ **technique** ce mot peut être utilisé en tant que synonyme de thérapie, comme le montre le texte suivant qui provient de [rapports de psychiatrie](https://www.em-consulte.com/article/13380/techniques-corporelles-en-therapeutique-psychiatri).

> Les troubles de la corporalité sont fréquemment rencontrés dans les troubles psychiatriques. À l'heure d'une évolution spontanée des prises en charge en psychiatrie vers des thérapies plus naturelles, c'est bien souvent en marge de la psychiatrie officielle que les thérapies corporelles se développent.
>
> Malgré leur nombre important (supérieur à 200) et de fortes disparités (origines, techniques utilisées, objectifs et indications thérapeutiques...), ces techniques peuvent être réunies autour de quelques points : elles visent une reprise de la verbalisation par le renouvellement des cénesthésies, et une récupération énergétique et narcissique grâce à une régression modulée et encadrée. Elles sont accessibles à de nombreux patients et de nombreuses pathologies, et sont dans l'ensemble remarquables par leur innocuité. Elles permettent d'établir une relation psychothérapique y compris, et peut-être préférentiellement, chez ceux qui ont un défaut dans l'expression verbale ou la communication (absence d'insight, personnalité fruste, inhibition anxieuse...). Elles utilisent comme objet de communication et comme moyen thérapeutique le propre corps du patient. Les résultats thérapeutiques de ces pratiques apparaissent souvent rapides et évidents.

On constate à partir du texte qui précède que « technique » peut être employé pour des choses aussi importantes qu'une thérapie (« les thérapies corporelles […] ces techniques peuvent être réunies […] »), mais aussi pour des procédures médicales qui font partie d'une thérapie ( « origines, techniques utilisées, objectifs et indications thérapeutiques...»).

Le mot « technique » convient donc assez bien. Cependant, il est possible d'être plus spécifique en se référant à ce que le résultat de l'action semble être inéluctablement.

> Outre les stimulus élémentaires les recherches psychologiques peuvent désigner comme stimulus des événements complexes, comme des mots ou des images, qui évoquent des connaissances ou des sentiments. ([Wikipédia, stimulus](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stimulus) )

- C’est peut-être un stimulus qui s’inscrit dans une quelconque thérapie comportementale voire une thérapie encore au stade expérimental.

La question de l'ironie (que j'allais oublier) ne se pose pas dans ce contexte. Aucun des termes considérés n'est propre à une formulation ironique ; il existe un emploi ironique, voire seulement badin,  de « technique », mais on doit l'utiliser dans un contexte dans lequel, justement, il n'est pas usuel.

- — Comment as-tu autant de succès avec ces filles ?
  — Tout est dans  la technique ! (*Si le second interlocuteur avait simplement répondu « Je ne sais pas, ce doit être la manière de m'y prendre. », on aurait pris cette réplique pour une évaluation sérieuse ; l'effet d'un mot qui évoque  la théorie, l'étude, la pratique assidue et consciente, produit un effet de badinerie certain.*)